# Matlab, Simulink & API

Tags: matlab, api, simulink

I have a Simulink Model with multiple levels and I wish to control it through a command. Is it possible to change levels using the `gcs` command to go to different levels?

For Ex:

```
gcs = ABC/abc/CDF/cdf
```

After running the command/function, the following should be the output:

```
gcs = ABC
```

Using `bdroot` would give me the same results, but `bdroot` does not change the actual level in Simulink, but just returns the root level of the model.

Comment: You can use open_system to open different levels. Once you use open_system, gcs will return the current system.